# Adding seconds to Intl.dateTimeFormat with React useEffect, useState, and setInterval

Tags: reactjs, date, settimeout

I have come across a weird problem where changing the order of a clone inside a setState() hook function changes the expected behavior.

I am trying to add one second to the value each second. However doing this directly causes the seconds to increase by two instead of one.

This works

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(new Date());

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(
  () =>
    setValue((value) => {
      const clonedDate = new Date(value.getTime());
      clonedDate.setSeconds(clonedDate.getSeconds() + 1); // Add one second to the time
      return clonedDate;
    }),
  1000
  );
  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, []);
```

This adds two seconds instead of one

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(new Date());

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(
  () =>
    setValue((value) => {
      value.setSeconds(value.getSeconds() + 1);
      const clonedDate = new Date(value.getTime());
      return clonedDate;
    }),
  1000
  );
  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Not sure but in first one you are creating new object every time then increasing the seconds but in second one you are incrementing in existing one then creating new object..it could be like it is holding the reference of previous value object in Second one

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is clear to me as that in the second version a state mutation is obviously occurring, but to be honest it isn't clear to me exactly where. It seems as though even though you are creating a ***new*** javascript `Date` object that it is still referencing properties of the previous data object.

Consider the following examples that exhibit identical behavior:

```
function App() {
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState({ c: 0 });
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState({ c: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(
      () =>
        setValue1((value) => {
          const clonedValue = { ...value };  // shallow copy first
          clonedValue.c = clonedValue.c + 1; // update copy
          return clonedValue;                // return copy
        }),
      1000
    );
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(
      () =>
        setValue2((value) => {
          value.c = value.c + 1;            // mutate current
          const clonedValue = { ...value }; // shallow copy
          return clonedValue;               // return copy
        }),
      1000
    );
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Non-mutaiton Version</h1>
      {value1.c}

      <h1>Mutation Version</h1>
      {value2.c}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit adding-seconds-to-intl-datetimeformat-with-react-useeffect-usestate-and-setint]

Interestingly though, if you remove the `React.StrictMode` from around `App` the two perform identically.

> StrictMode currently helps with:
>
> - Identifying components with unsafe lifecycles
> - Warning about legacy string ref API usage
> - Warning about deprecated findDOMNode usage
> - ***Detecting unexpected side effects***
> - Detecting legacy context API

[Detecting unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by **intentionally double-invoking the following functions**:

- Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
- Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
- ***Function component bodies***
- State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
- Functions passed to **`useState`**, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`

Demo with your original date objects running in both StrictMode and non-StrictMode:

[image: Edit adding-seconds-to-intl-datetimeformat-with-react-useeffect-usestate-and-setint (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with below line it is mutating the value object. You don't need to call value.setSeconds, value.getSeconds()+1 itSelf is enough to increment seconds by 1.

```
Replace below line of code  -



   const interval = setInterval(
      () =>
        setValue2((value2) => {
          let second = value2.getSeconds() +1;
         
          //value2.setSeconds(second);
           let newTime = new Date();
          newTime.setSeconds(second);
          const clonedDate = new Date(newTime.getTime());
          return clonedDate;
        }),
      1000
    );
```

Comment: @Drew Rees ...if you will uncomment the commented code (//value2.setSeconds(second);) it will again start incrementing by 2 Seconds.